# Write bitarray to file in python?

Tags: python, file-io

I am trying to write a pit array to a file in python as in this example: [python bitarray to and from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266330/python-bitarray-to-and-from-file)

however, I get garbage in my actual test file:

```
test_1 = ^@^@
test_2 = ^@^@
```

code:

```
from bitarray import bitarray

def test_function(myBitArray):
    test_bitarray=bitarray(10)
    test_bitarray.setall(0)

    with open('test_file.inp','w') as output_file:
        output_file.write('test_1 = ')
        myBitArray.tofile(output_file)
        output_file.write('\ntest_2 = ')
        test_bitarray.tofile(output_file)
```

Any help with what's going wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you on Windows? If so, set the file mode to `wb`.

Comment: what happens if you print bitarray before writing it

Comment: @JoranBeasley: That's just going to print `<class 'bitarray.bitarray'>`. Presumably you wanted to print `test_bitarray`, yes? That will print `bitarray('0000000000')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not garbage. The `tofile` function writes binary data to a binary file. A 10-bit-long `bitarray` with all 0's will be output as two bytes of 0. (The docs explain that when the length is not a multiple of 8, it's padded with 0 bits.) When you read that as text, two 0 bytes will look like `^@^@`, because `^@` is the way (many) programs represent a 0 byte as text.

If you want a human-readable text-friendly representation, use the `to01` method, which returns a human-readable strings. For example:

```
with open('test_file.inp','w') as output_file:
    output_file.write('test_1 = ')
    output_file.write(myBitArray.to01())
    output_file.write('\ntest_2 = ')
    output_file(test_bitarray.to01())
```

Or maybe you want this instead:

```
output_file(str(test_bitarray))
```

… which will give you something like:

```
bitarray('0000000000')
```